# no compatible targets were found - rca tablet

Tags: android, eclipse

Looked at all the prior questions but they do not help. I just got a rca '7" Dual Core 8GB' (RCT6378W2) tablet. It runs android 4.2.2 and came without a usb cable so its connected with my (flip) phone's cable which works to view its files. I'm running win 8.1 and the adt bundle from google updated with what I need from the sdk maneger. Usb debugging is enabled. Manifest has

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

It still says `no compatible targets were found`. The application does run with an emulator. Whats left is to update drivers but the help website (http://www.rcatablets.com/help-desk) provides none.

How do I effectively build and debug and test on my device. Using an emulator isn't practical on my laptop isn't practical and is kinda why I've stopped developing since march.

**Update:** At some point it stopped being recognized again. Just had to add the device again to `.android\adb_usb.ini` and run `adb kill-server` and `adb devices` again.

Comment: It is due to setting in the device...non-market app and USB debugging should be allowed.

Comment: @MD / @M D ?  USB debugging is enabled as I originally said and I don't see an option for non-market app in any settings tab.

Comment: you just find "Unknown sources" option into Settings->Security->Unknown sources. You must turn on this option.

Comment: @MD / @M D (which is right?) Still no. screenshots of settings http://i.imgur.com/sYOUJOo.png

Comment: You're set all the option so ,now just try to reinstall the Driver

Comment: @MD / @M D "Whats left is to update drivers but the help website (http://www.rcatablets.com/help-desk) provides none." Even tried the google drivers but of course they don't work. Though I used the contact support form to ask for help after posting the question here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44296/discussion-between-m-d-and-old-badman-grey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More detailed and Windows instructions are here: http://ryancuda.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-get-working-adb-drivers-for.html

For my Mac, I was able to connect after doing:

1. `android update adb`
2. Find your adb_usb.ini file (`locate adb_usb.ini`, mine was in `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`)
3. Get Vendor ID from running `system_profiler SPUSBDataType`.  Look for your model or serial number.  Mine was "0x2207" for my RCA 7" which showed up as "Fuzhou Rockchip Electronics Co., Ltd."
4. Add the id to the end of the `adb_usb.ini` file `echo "0x2207" >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini`
5. `adb kill-server`
6. `adb devices`
7. Accept the computer's key on the prompt on your device